# How to manually set a special resolution?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit for the past short time. After a screen upgrade, I can't use/set the right resolution.

My old display setting was three 17" of 1280x1024 behind a Matrox TripleHead2GO connected to a Nvidia GTX480. All was working fine with a virtual resolution of 3840x1024.

(TripleHead2GO emulate a single screen of the total resolution for the OS.)

Now, I've upgraded to three 24" of 1920x1080 for a virtual resolution of 5760x1080.
But I don't see this resolution on the Ubuntu Display Settings nor in the xrandr list.

How should I use this higher resolution?

Answer (score 1):

As my blog post, [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html), suggests

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "1600x900_60.00"
sudo xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

1. First command creates a new mode with resolution 1600x900
2. Second command makes it available for use, with display (in this case VBOX0)
3. Third command selects the newly added mode as the display resolution for the specified display

To change this to any custom resolution, just replace 1600 with the width you want and 900 with the height you want.

Comment: Not exactly, the only change of 1600x900 won't be enough, but I understand the process and I have tried:

`cvt 5760 1080 50
sudo xrandr --newmode "5760x1080" 424.75  5760 6088 6696 7632  1080 1083 1093 1114 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-I-3 5760x1080
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32`

Any other pointers ?